# Can a React blog be indexed by search engines?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm currently developing a blog with React, Node.js, Express, Sequelize, ... and I asked myself a question : will my articles be indexed by search engines ? Or will only the home page of my site be indexed ?

For example if I've an article *How to foo bar* at the URL `blog.com/how-to-foo-bar`, will this URL be listed in Google if somebody search *How to foo bar* ?

I heard of Gatsby to generate static sites and Next for SSR but but I don't know anything about it, should I rather use these tools to make my blog ?

Comment: If your url returns server rendered content then the search engines should be able to index it.

Comment: Google [says it can render JS](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/fix-search-javascript), and you can also [preview](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289) how it renders your page. That does not apply for other bots of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend server side rendering for having an indexed site. If you develop the site like a web-app and it runs only with JavaScript, you can be lucky to get indexed, but it really depends on the crawler, how long loading your site takes and probably the current resources of the visiting bot while it does the crawling ([from a session I attended at JS Kongress with info from mid 2019](https://github.com/JSKongress/JS-Kongress-Munich-Deep-Track/blob/035862b7e212889ad3edde0983910e06f709b256/2019/technical-seo/README.md#technical-seo)).

If you need indexing (blogs, shops, etc.) and want to be safe, do the server side rendering. Gatsby essentially does that, as well as Next. So you can safely develop with React and use these tools / frameworks to get it more or less for free. If you already have something and do not want to switch to something else, you could have a look into tools that prerender your pages and serve the result.

From my experience, doing SSR on the fly doesn't work out well as it takes a lot of time to do for the server, resulting in long loading times for the user.

Doing SSR up front, cache the result, pushing the cached version to clients and let them hydrate the state does work, but it needs a lot of effort and correctness to get it right. The tools you've mentioned do basically that for you without you having to worry too much about it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I'm gonna use Next.js !

Answer (score 1):

If you host your React app on service like Netlify, you can enable its 'Prerendering' service. When their CDN software determines if a request comes from a crawler, they will serve up the prerendered content, and thus your articles will be indexed by search engines.

However, it takes time for this service to prerender your pages, Netlify for example, will cache prerendered pages for between 24 and 48 hours. Learn more about [Netlify Prerendering](https://docs.netlify.com/site-deploys/post-processing/prerendering)

If you are using React and Express.js, I would recommend you to learn Next.js. It does both Server Side Rendering (SSR) and Static Site Generation (SSG). You can also build your API with Next.js which are serverless functions. I suggest you to checkout `Next.js` [tutorials](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app) which is easy to follow.

In my opinion, if you are using React for production sites, you should always consider using Next.js or Gatsby.js.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into the concept of `robots.txt`, if you're not already familiar. Or go with one of the suggested frameworks...